# How to start a java application as a windows service with procrun?

Tags: java, windows-services, executable-jar, procrun

I'm starting a java application as a windows service using apache `procrun`. It works in general, but when I inspect my service it tells me it is not running, even as it is!

installed service:

```
set PR_JVM=auto
set PR_CLASSPATH=...
set PR_STARTUP=auto
set PR_STARTMODE=jvm
set PR_STARTCLASS=...
set PR_STARTMETHOD=...
REM run service within a console window
prunsrv.exe //IS//ServiceName
```

run the service:

```
start prunsrv.exe
```

monitor the service:

```
prunmgr.exe //ES//ServiceName
```

Result: shows the service configuration where I could start the service, means: the manager assumes the service is NOT started.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I had my service folder on a drive that was created using `subst`. When moving the files to a real existing hard drive, it worked as expected.